# Moving LXC container's backing storage

Tags: lxc

I have a bunch of LXC containers running on a machine. All of them have their rootfs in the default location `/var/lib/lxc/*/rootfs`. This directory lives on a rather small partition on the host. I have a much, much bigger partition mounted on `/home`.

Is there an option to move the backing storage to `/home`? Preferably per container.

I know I could have done that *before* I had a couple of running containers (`lxc-create -P PATH`). But now they're up and I don't want to lose them.

Comment: Can't you make `/var/lib/lxc` a symbolic link to a directory in `/home`?

Comment: ... That was so obvious I didn't think of it. It works. Wow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

rootfs is the configuration option.  If the container is stopped, you can move the backing directory wherever you want and specify that in the config file:

```
lxc.rootfs = /home/utsname
```

This is probably better than using a symlink.

LXC also allows backing files.  You can use block devices and raw images.

Source: https://linuxcontainers.org/lxc/manpages/man5/lxc.container.conf.5.html

Answer (score 3):

I, personally prefer a different approach.
Given that the OS part of the containers is relatively small (max. 2GB a debian jessie server with plenty of services running, about 3Gb a working ubuntu image with remote desktop), I leave the OS reside in /var/lib/lxc and use a separate partition for the container's data.

This is simply accomplished modifing the /var/lib/lxc/container/fstab file:

```
/mnt/data/container-data/ /var/lib/lxc/container/rootfs/home/        none    bind    0       0
```

Create the folders (both source and target) on the main host, stop your container, move your data and restart the container!

In the case above, both direcories reside on a /mnt/data partition on the lxc host, in my case a large disk.

There are many advantages associated with this method: splitting the OS and the data allows you to rapidly copy and start test containers when you have to accomplish hazardous tasks (ex: "aptitude -f dist-upgrade"):

- stop the container (the partitions in fstab will detach from the /var/lib/lxc/container/rootfs/ directory):

  ```
  lxc-stop -n container
  ```
- copy the container:

  ```
  mkdir /var/lib/lxc/containertest
  rsync -Pavv /var/lib/lxc/container/ /var/lib/lxc/containertest/
  ```

Remember to modify accordingly /var/lib/lxc/containertest/config and /var/lib/lxc/containertest/fstab

- start the new containertest, work with it and see the results!

  ```
  lxc-start -n containertest
  ```

Also, answering to your concerns, you should not worry about not haveing done this *before*: one of the great advanages of lxc is it's versatility!

Answer (score 3):

Call me lazy - but why mess around with the config files if you could (bind) mount your large directory at /var/lib/lxc?

Simply shutdown your containers, move things over to /home/lxc/whatever and bind-mount them back in - done!

Answer (score 1):

Better to change path for all new containers by default:

```
# vim /etc/lxc/lxc.conf
lxc.lxcpath=/media/other/programs/OS/containers/
```

All containers will be in `/media/other/programs/OS/containers/` directory

All old containers move via `mv` and edit configs for them as this guy https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/191620/53139